# Dogleg Method versus Constrained (Quasi)Newton's Step

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I do not understand the point of the dogleg method. If I have an estimate of the Hessian available, why wouldn't I just take a (Quasi)Newton step and stop it at the boundary?

My problem is:

$min_{p} \quad f(x) + p^{T} \nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2} p^{T} \nabla^{2} f(x) p\\ s.t. ||p||_{2} \leq \Delta$

The dogleg method says to solve this by solving for $\tau$:

$|| p_{u} + (\tau-1)(p_{b}-p_{u})||_{2}^{2} = \Delta^{2}$

Where:

$p_{u} = -\frac{g^{T}{g}}{g^{T}Bg}g\\
p_{b} = -B^{-1}g\\
g \approx \nabla f(x)\\
B \approx \nabla^{2} f(x)$

But isn't $p_{b}$ simply the (Quasi)Newton step? Why wouldn't I just always do something like:

$p = -\frac{\Delta}{||B^{-1} g||}B^{-1} g$

How is the dogleg method any better? Especially when the trust region radius $\Delta$ is large enough that there is some curvature but the 2nd order model still provides a good fit, I see no point of using the dogleg approach.

Where should I use the dogleg method over the (Quasi)Newton's Step?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is if you're far away from the minimum, taking steps in steepest descent direction $g$ usually converges fastest. When close to the minimum the Gauss-newton steps converge faster. Dogleg is using a linear combination of the two to try to achieve a reasonable tradeoff

Comment: So is it true that far away from the minimum, $\tau$ will tend to 1, while closer to the minimum, $\tau$ will tend to 2? As long as $\Delta$ is suitably chosen that is.

Comment: The logic in selecting the step is typically: 1. If the Gauss-Newton (GN) point is inside the trust region use it (since GN is the overall minimizer of the unconstrained problem). In this case we are likely close to the minimum. 2. If GN and SD are both outside then take a step in the SD direction, truncating at the trust region boundary. Here we are likely far away from the minimum. 3. If SD is inside and GN is outside, take the dogleg step (by computing $\tau$) and use a combination of both directions.

Comment: Do you know if there are any convergence results for dogleg method?